# Take file from file system and pass it as a File object

Tags: java, file, file-upload, file-io

I have been uploading files from a website quite happily using a combination of Play Framework (1.2.4) with Java and jQuery/javascript.

On the client side I attach a blob object to a `FormData` object and then send that to my Play Framework controller, which accepts the file. I have written a class `UploadImg` to upload this file to Amazon S3. I then initiate the class by passing in a File object and filename (which is a String), and call the `doUpload()` method:

```
public static void myController(File f){
    UploadImg imgToUpload = new UploadImg(File file, String filename);
    imgToUpload.doUpload();
    // ...
```

I now have a bunch of images on my desktop and I writing a 'bulk uploader'. I did something lik:

```
 File img = new File("/pics/Repin 301.jpg");
 UploadImg fileToUpload = new UploadImg(img);
 fileToUpload.doUpload()
```

But I get an error telling me that my input is null.

Comment: Looks like the file `Repin 301.jpg` doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmm ... it exists in Finder, will look into permission etc.

Comment: Can you give more of the error/exception that you see.

Answer (score 1):

The path /pics/ doesn't look like it would point to your desktop, if pics is relative to where you are running the app from then drop the leading slash.

Try this to confirm the file is being found:

```
File img = new File("/pics/Repin 301.jpg");
if(img.exists()) {
     UploadImg fileToUpload = new UploadImg(img);
    fileToUpload.doUpload()
}else{
     System.out.println("File not found");
}
```